# Code first: Where's the connection string & the Database?

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm testing how code first works. Here's how I defined the Context

```
public class EfDbContext: Context
{
  public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't create any data base, but I was able to do all the CRUD operations.

Now I don't see the connection string in my web.config. I don't see either the Database. I've checked the App_Data Directory and also the Sql Server Express. I don't see any trace of the Database created.

Yet, everything is perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF code-first will use a connection string that has the same name as your DB context - so you could define it like this:

```
<connectionString>
   <add name="EfDbContext" 
        connectionString="server=YourServer;database=YourChoice;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionString>
```

The database won't be created by default, until you actually do something, e.g. it should show up as soon as you make a call to `EfDbContext.SaveChanges()` for the first time.

It will be called the same as your DB context (`YourNamespace.EfDbContext`) if you haven't defined your own, custom connection string, and it should show up in your default local SQL instance.

See from the [ADO.NET EF 4.1 Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx):

> ***Where’s My Data?***
>
> *DbContext by convention created a database for you on
>   localhost\SQLEXPRESS. The database is named after the fully qualified
>   name of your derived context, in our case that is
>   “CodeFirstSample.ProductContext”. We’ll look at ways to change this
>   later in the walkthrough.*